# Java: argument list error in integer declaration

Tags: java, class, methods, int, declaration

So I'm getting an error in line 18, it describes:

```
HelloWorld.java:18: error: method calcThirdChance in class HelloWorld cannot be applied to given    types;
     int t3 = calcThirdChance(t1+t2);
              ^
required: int,int
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This makes little sense to me, because the method calcThirdChance returns a single int and I am declaring only one int in that line therefore I don't know why is it requiring 2 ints, which is allegedly the reason of the error.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    System.out.println(simMin(70,80));
 }
 public static int calcThirdChance(int t1, int t2){
    int c;
     c = -1*(t1+t2);
    double finalsend;
     finalsend = Math.pow(2.71, c/100)*2;
    finalsend*=150;
     return (int)finalsend;
 }
 public static int simMin(int t1, int t2){
     int t3 = calcThirdChance(t1+t2);
     int total=t1+t2+t3;
     int play = 50;
     if(play<=t1){
         return t1;
     }
     else if(play<=t1+t2){
         return t2;
     }
     else{
         return t3;
     }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`calcThirdChance` takes 2 arguments

```
int t3 = calcThirdChance(t1, t2);
```

Comment: But returns only 1, I need the value that calcThirdCHance returns, which is only 1 int. t1 and t2 are already declared

Comment: @user1832697 And you will have it in `t3`.

Answer (score 2):

The error you got has nothing to do with the return type of `calcThirdChance`.

You are passing a single argument to the method :

```
calcThirdChance(t1+t2);
```

You need to pass two :

```
calcThirdChance(t1,t2);
```

BTW, seeing that `calcThirdChance(int t1, int t2)` only needs the sums of the arguments it receives, you can change it to :

```
public static int calcThirdChance(int t)
{
    int c;
    c = -1*t;
    double finalsend;
    finalsend = Math.pow(2.71, c/100)*2;
    finalsend*=150;
    return (int)finalsend;
}
```

This would make the call `calcThirdChance(t1+t2)` valid.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
calcThirdChance(t1+t2);
```

passes the result of `t1+t2` (one value), but your method takes two. I think you wanted

```
calcThirdChance(t1, t2); // <-- a comma
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I lost my glasses and I can't see properly